# how to create a nested index in ElasticSearch with Python?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am using bulk index in [elasticsearch-py](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/) to add documents that contain nested items in the form of arrays of dictionaries (`address` in this case):

```
{'Name': 'Smith, John',
 'ID': '3327',
 'Nationality': 'English',
 'address': [
      {
      'ID': '5',
      'City': 'Milwaukee',
      'Latlon': '43.0526,-87.9199',
      'State': 'WI'
      },
     ... 
  ]
}
```

I create a list of actions, one for each document like so:

```
{
   "_index": "myindex",
   "_type": "mytype",
   "_source": the_doc
}
```

And then push the actions via `helpers.bulk(es, actions)`

I want to specify that `address` is a nested object. Where do I indicate this to ES with `elasticsearch-py`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/issues/278#issuecomment-145923743

I used the [DSL library](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-dsl-py/). I created a `mytype.py` file:

```py
from elasticsearch_dsl import DocType, Nested, String

class MyType(DocType):
    name = String()
    nationality = String()

    address = Nested(
        include_in_parent=True,
        properties={
            'location': String(),
            'state': String(),
            'city': String(),
        }
    )
```

Then I include this file and put the mappings into elasticsearch with [`include_in_parent`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-nested-type.html) to allow for highlighting and others:

```py
from elasticsearch_dsl import Index
from mytype import MyType

myindex = Index('myindex')
myindex.doc_type(MyType)
myindex.create()
```

Comment: Since you specified the doc type as part of the index, how did you proceed to use helpers.bulk?

Comment: @dter i did it in two phases: first i create the index itself as described then build the action array with the proper structure (my actions don't use the custom class but a dictionary) and push it via `helpers.bulk`. the custom class ensures that the actions get mapped properly in the index. not sure if it is the *right* way to do it but it works for me